# Intent extra fields not updated

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I create a notification with an activity like this,

```
 public static void buildNotification(Context context, int id, String notiContent){
          NotificationManager notificationManager 
          = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

          Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotifyActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("notiContent", notiContent);
          intent.putExtra("notiId", id);
          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);


          PendingIntent pendingIntent 
          = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

          builder
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
          .setContentTitle("")
          .setContentText(notiContent)
          .setContentInfo(""+Math.random())
          .setTicker("!")
          .setLights(0xFFFF0000, 500, 500) //setLights (int argb, int onMs, int offMs)
          .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
          .setAutoCancel(true);

          Notification notification = builder.build();
          nc++;
          notificationManager.notify(nc, notification);
 }
```

however the `onCreate` method allways gets the same extra data (`notiId`).

how to force recreation of Intent ? or is there any other way to pass extra data to activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onResume()` method and use `intent.setAction("intentAction");` and get it in `onResume()`

Comment: actually, `intent.setAction` seems to update the intent while `putExtra` not :)

Answer (score 0):

use `SharedPreferences` in `onPause()` in your activity where u want to get updated value of `notid` as below:

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() 
{
  super.onPause(); 
  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
  editor.putString("notid", "Your notid value"); // value to store
  editor.commit();    
}
```

and get the value of notid as below:

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", 0);
  String notid= preferences.getString("notid");
```

Comment: that would be same as using a static class field, which is not ekhm threadsafe :)